# React-Table: Get selectedRowIds in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm rendering a react-table and need to know which rows are selected in the parent component.

**Here is my table component:**

```
const TableComponent = (props) => {
  const { columns, data } = props;
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state: { selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useRowSelect
  );

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
                ))}
            </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.slice(0, 10).map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                    return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                    );
                })}
                </tr>
            );
            })}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

**And here is the parent:**

```
function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName",
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age",
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits",
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status",
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(10, 3), []);

  return (
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  );
}
```

I need to know the `selectedRowIds` in the parent component. Does anyone know how I'd get those from the child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expose the method from `child component` with `useImperativeHandleHook` [imperativehandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle).

And with the help of this hook, you can get the selected row ids in the parent component.

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getSelectedRows:()=> selectedRowIds 
}),[selectedRowIds]);
```

And in parent component you have to call the method with **ref** as
`parentRef.current.getSelectedRows()`

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Cool! So do I pass ref down to the child as a prop?

Comment: yes you can pass it as prop, and in child component use forwardRef.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: @ShubhamJ. Could you please elaborate how to solve this

Comment: @NitinT, you have to use useImperativeHandle hook in your child component, from where you are having the context of selectedRowIds.
And getSelectedRows will be the function you have to call using ref from its parent component